# How to click on the link from "Page 1" to the required paragraph "Pages 2"?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I plan to make a content management system.

**System composition**:
    - Pages by category. (Pages by Category);
    - Text editor. (Text editor);

The text of the pages contains formatted text, pictures.
Text in HTML format is stored in the database.
The category tree prints text from the database to a text editor.

**Logics**
1. In "PagesByCategory" there is a tree of pages;
2. Each page consists of lines;
Page 1:
- Line 1 Page 1;
- Line 2 Page 1;
- Line 3 Page 1.
Page 2:
- Line 1 Page 2;
- Line 2 Page 2;
- Line 3 Page 2.
3. I select a page in the tree (For example: "Page 1");
4. The page is displayed in "TextEditor";
5. I read the page in "TextEditor";
6. On page "Page 1" I see the link to "Line 2 Page 2";
7. I click the link.
8. In "TextEditor" opens "Page 2", the scroll stops at "Line 2".

**Question**
How do I place links to a piece of text on another page?
That is, on "Page 1" there is a reference to "Page 2" "a fragment of the text".

[image: image link !!!]

Comment: This question is far too broad to be easily answered by a single answer.  Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: you are using devexpress control?

Comment: @BaskarJohn In the picture yes.
But I do not know yet whether I will use it or not.
If this simplifies the task, I will use it.

Do you want to say something about this?

Comment: @climivin in case you are using devexpress just read [this](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/7397/Controls-and-Libraries/Rich-Text-Editor/RichEditControl-Document/Document-Elements/Hyperlinks-and-Bookmarks)

Comment: @BaskarJohn Updated question

If there is a ready solution, I think to use "devexpress".
 Only in "devexpress" is the transition within the document. 
In my solution, the pages lie in the list of database records. That is, the transition must be performed to the text fragment of the desired record.

How to do it?